# Zip only data from folder in Linux

Tags: linux, zip

I have a folder with some data like this:

```
folder
    |- data1.txt
    |- data2.html ...
    |- folder1
          |- other data ...
    ... (some folders or data)
...
```

and would like to archive only data from `folder` (with embedded folders without root folder) using `zip`. If use `zip -r archive.zip folder/*` the result is:

```
archive.zip
    |-folder
        |- data1.txt
        |- data2.html ...
        |- folder1
              |- other data ...
        ... (some folders or data)
    ...
```

but I need

```
archive.zip
    |- data1.txt
        |- data2.html ...
        |- folder1
              |- other data ...
        ... (some folders or data)
    ...
```

Which command can I use to get this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter to the root folder and issue:

```
zip -r archive.zip *
```